# Takes too much time to display a page that waits for a bluetooth input

Tags: android, asynchronous, bluetooth, arduino, handler

I'd like to display a red button if I get a certain input from arduino device which is connected via bluetooth. My code looks like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    blueconnect(); //creates my bluetooth connection

    if (waitarrival() == 1)
        Global.fullpaper = 1;


    if (Global.fullpaper == 1) {
        View paperbutton = findViewById(R.id.buttonPaper);
        paperbutton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);}


}
```

and

```
public int waitarrival()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = Global.mmInStream.read(buffer);
            if (bytes ==  30) //send 30 when trashcan finishes the movement sequence
                return 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and my arduino code simply:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin (9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  Serial.write(30);
}
```

When I first start my code, it just shows a white screen. If I wait long enough (like 10 seconds) red button is actually displayed. However this is too much waiting time... How can I fix this? Any help will be really appreciated at this point. Thank you in advance.

Edit: =======================================================================

I created the AsyncTask Class:

```
private class switchcolors extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
{
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void...params) 
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
        long targetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 50000; //wait for 50s


        while( System.currentTimeMillis() < targetTime ) 
        {
            try 
            {
                bytes = Global.mmInStream.read(buffer);
                if (bytes > 0)
                {
                    if (buffer[0] == 30) //send 30 from arduino ( Serial.write(30) )
                        return 1;
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {}
        }

        return 0;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
    {
        if (result == 1)
        {
            View paperbutton = findViewById(R.id.buttonPaper);
            paperbutton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);           
        }
    }
}
```

and use this class in onCreate() method:

```
new switchcolors().execute();
```

The page is correctly displayed but red button is not showed... Can I get some help?

Edit 2 ================================================
Never mind. The above works! It was my Bluetooth device that had a connection problem

Comment: `blueconnect` should run off the ui thread. Wrap it in an AsyncTask for now. Keep in mind that bt might not be connected right away, so you'll have to either queue the click, or keep the button disabled until bt is connected. FWIW, I have bt connection in less than a second to an arduino-based device. Post your btconnect code.

Comment: @323go There is actually no problem establishing the connection. If I remove the "if(waitarrival() ..." part, the page is displayed in a second. I believe this line is causing the waiting. Could you help me understand how to asynchronously handle that method instead of indefinitely waiting for it to return???

Comment: Oh, gotcha... misread your code there. Yes, the `read(buffer)` call is blocking, so it would block your app until it times out. Use `available()` to see if any bytes are ready to be read before reading them. The better pattern would be to create a client thread which does all the i/o operations.

Comment: Also, `InputStream.read()` returns the *number of bytes read*, not the actual byte. That's written into the buffer, so you'd want to check `buffer[0]==30` to return your result.

Comment: @323go I really appreciate your input! I'm pretty new to android dev so could you help me understand how to use available()?

Comment: Sure... let me place it in the answer to get better formatting.

Comment: @323go Oh wow buffer[0] was the way to go! It returns right away. I really appreciate this, I missed that... One more question, is there any way to display the page content first and then read the input??

Comment: Yes, see the answer -- you want to offload the waitforarrival into an async-task.

Comment: Sorry was offline a bit. All good now?

Comment: @323go yes the code is working great! but I have one more question. Is there anyway to check the data read periodically? right now, it's checking only once

Comment: Sure. Create a `Handler mHandler` and a `Runnable mCheckRunnable` in your onCreate. The `Runnable` should do the check, and `mHandler.postDelayed( mCheckRunnable, 1000 );`. You also want to add this `postDelayed` to your `onResume()`, and then add `mHandler.removeCallbacks( mCheckRunnable );` to your `onPause`. This will run this every second (you can adjust the `1000` to suit your needs, while the activity is running. It'll stop the checks onPause and restart them onResume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `waitarrival()` is blocking your ui thread, specifically the call to `read()`.

What you'd want to do instead is:

```
public int waitarrival() {
    while( Global.mmInStream.available() > 1 ) { // at least one byte available
        byte data = Global.mmInStream.read(); // read just one byte, that's all we need
        if( data == 30 ) {
            return 1; // if we received the '30' we were looking for, then we're good to go.
        }
    }
    return 0; // this is returned in all other cases -- i.e. no byte available, or no 30s.
}
```

Once that's done, you'd probably want check this periodically to see if there was a reaction from the bluetooth device. You could look at the Android Bluetooth Chat sample to see how to properly put the entire thing on a background thread -- that's the preferred pattern for this.

If you're really want to wait for this, and handle your own timeout, you could wrap this entire method into an `AsyncTask`, with something like this --

```
protected Integer doInBackGround( Integer[] timeout ) {
    long targetTime = System.CurrentTimeMillis() + timeout[0] * 1000; // time out in seconds...

    while( System.CurrentTimeMillis() < targetTime ) {
       if( waitforarrival() == 1 )
           return 1;
       Thread.sleep(100); // sleep 1/10th of a second
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Your `onPostExecute()` would then update the UI based on the result.

And then you'd invoke it from `onCreate()` like so:

```
myTask.execute( 60 ); // wait for arrival for a minute.
```

Comment: Thanks so much you are awesome!! I will definitely try this. I will get back to you on how this went.

Comment: Hi, I tried using AsyncTask but I seem to have done something wrong. I edited my original post, could you check?